# Is there a way to save the selected text and highlight it again once the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to select the text and save that selection in localStorage or DB, and I could highlight the previously selected text by reading it back from the storage. But if the selected text is on multiple location in the page then all the instances get highlighted which I do not want. I can grab the left and top of the selected text but in case of font resizing, the left/top changes. I'm not sharing any code here because there is nothing to share related to this. FYI, I'm referring to iBooks app in ipad which has the same feature and I'm willing to know how does it do it properly?

**Update:** I tried a new approach wherein i add markers around the selected text using which I could figure out the start and end of the selected string to be highlighted later. You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/jE4w5/

but in iPad `rangeCount` is not working, Is there any workaround for iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get information about the current selection using [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) - at least in modern browsers. It will return a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) object, you could start with playing with the properties supplied by that object:

- **anchorNode**
  Returns the node in which the selection begins.
- **anchorOffset**
  Returns the number of characters that the selection's anchor is offset within the anchorNode.
- **focusNode**
  Returns the node in which the selection ends.
- **focusOffset**
  Returns the number of characters that the selection's focus is offset within the focusNode.
- **isCollapsed**
  Returns a Boolean indicating whether the selection's start and end points are at the same position.
- **rangeCount**
  Returns the number of ranges in the selection.

Also, using the [`getRangeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection/getRangeAt) method, you could get the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Range) objects from the Selection, which supply more useful methods and properties.

I don't know how far you want to go with this solution, and your question is quite general, so this is more like a direction you could go rather than a ready-to-use solution.

Comment: Hey @bažmegakapa, thanks for a wonderful answer. I've updated my question's details and added a demo as well. Please check. Thanks!

Comment: @codef0rmer Looks nice. I did not know it did not work in iPad, I see no reason for that... maybe ask a new, specific question regarding that issue?